# Does agvtool work under Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, agvtool

I'm trying to update my marketing version using `agvtool`.

```
agvtool new-marketing-version 1.0.2
```

> Setting CFBundleShortVersionString of
>   project Newsgroup to: 
>       1.0.2.
>
> Updating CFBundleShortVersionString in
>   Info.plist(s)...
>
> Updated CFBundleShortVersionString in
>   "Newsgroup.xcodeproj/../Newsgroup-Info.plist"
>   to 1.0.2 Updated
>   CFBundleShortVersionString in
>   "Newsgroup.xcodeproj/../Test
>   Classes/Tests-Info.plist" to 1.0.2

```
agvtool what-marketing-version
```

> No marketing version number
>   (CFBundleShortVersionString) found for
>   Jambase targets.
>
> Looking for marketing version in
>   native targets... Looking for
>   marketing version
>   (CFBundleShortVersionString) in native
>   targets...
>
> Found CFBundleShortVersionString of ""
>   in
>   "Newsgroup.xcodeproj/../Newsgroup-Info.plist"
>   Found CFBundleShortVersionString of ""
>   in "Newsgroup.xcodeproj/../Test
>   Classes/Tests-Info.plist"

Xcode is not open when I'm running these commands… Is there anything else I could be doing wrong or is `agvtool` broken under Xcode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is changed since Xcode 3.x, but you need to add `CFBundleShortVersionString` to the `-Info.plist` files. If you open the plist in Xcode it's called "Bundle Version Strings, short". Add that value to your plists, set the marketing version using `avgtool`, then get the marketing version out with `agvtool what-marketing-version -terse1`, which returns just the value of the first marketing version string it encounters.

Comment: What about for projects with multiple targets?  I keep getting the wrong CFBundleShortVersionString, because it's picking the wrong target with agvtool mvers -terse1

Comment: You can have multiple plist for multiple targets